# Infinite loop because the iterator doesn't move

Tags: java, loops, iterator

There is a some class which implementing an interface `Selector`. I should use `iterator()` in its methods.

```
private class SequenceSelector implements Selector {
    private T obj = items.iterator().next();
    public boolean end() { return !items.iterator().hasNext(); }
    public T current() { return obj; }
    public void next() { obj = items.iterator().next(); }
}
```

`items` is a ArrayList. `obj` is a value in order to save the first sequence member before the first `next()` using.

With a following code the program goes into an infinite loop in which is printed only the first member of sequence.

```
while(!selector.end()) {
      System.out.print(selector.current() + " ");
      selector.next();
}
```

Why does this happens? Though I use `next()` method, the iterator doesn't move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `items.iterator()` you create a new iterator.

Create one iterator at the start, and use that repeatedly.

```
private class SequenceSelector implements Selector {
    private final Iterator<T> iterator = items.iterator();

    private T obj = iterator.next();
    public boolean end() { return !iterator.hasNext(); }
    public T current() { return obj; }
    public void next() { obj = iterator.next(); }
}
```